# Protecting cells in excel using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013

I have an excel sheet and a windows form in visual studio 2013. The form allows users to enter data in excel sheet. It will be shared by multiple users. What I want to do is that certain cells in excel (eg: column B to G) should be locked but data entry in these cells should be allowed through the form. Once a user opens excel, they can edit other columns but not these columns. 
I locked the cells and protected the worksheet in excel. Then, in my vb code I added these:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
              xlWorkBook =   xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test.xlsx")
          'xlApp.Visible = True
           xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlWorkBook.Unprotect()

   'entering data in excel

    xlWorkBook.Save()
    xlWorkBook.Protect()
End Sub
```

I get the error saying that 'the cells you are trying to enter data is protected.' something like this. 
What should I do?
Please help!!

Comment: Let's continue here. No, I mean, if there is no password to "protect" the cells, then any user can still unprotect it, right? And lastly, the workbook is really the one protected? or the worksheet?

Comment: ya @CrushSundae but they'll have to open excel, click on review tab and then unprotect it. Anyway, I'll add password afterwards. My main concern right now is how to allow data entry in the locked cells through the form. I protected only sheet1

Comment: No, you're on the right direction. You cannot enter records to the cell because it is protected. So check whether the protection is on the Workbook or Worksheet level.

Comment: In my testing (not thru code), I tried protecting Excel by worksheet and by workbook. Removed the protection by workbook and still cannot edit unless I also remove the protection from worksheet.

Comment: It is on worksheet level I think. Because only Sheet1 is protected in excel

Comment: @CrushSundae in my code I changed xlWorkBook.Protect() and xlWorkBook.Unprotect() to xlWorksheet.Protect() and unprotect. It allows me to enter data but when I click submit it asks me do you want to save the file? I don't want this prompt message to show up. It should automatically save the file. Any input on this?

Comment: `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` will do the work.

Comment: But will it save my data in excel?

Comment: Yup. It will just remove the confirmations alert.

Comment: I was trying that. It worked! Thank you!! But it entirely removes the protection from the sheet. What I mean is when I open excel there is no protection. But I want the protection to be there

Comment: Then protect the worksheet again. The one you're protecting before is the workbook.

Comment: I changed my code to xlWorksheet.Unprotect() then code for entering data and then xlWorksheet.Protect()

Comment: -_- see your code? You saved first before you protect. So the protect change you made wasn't saved.

Comment: Oops ya my bad! It works now. Thank you so much!
How do I accept your answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per our discussion:

The problem with your code is you are unprotecting the **Workbook** but the ones that are really protected is your **Worksheets**.

Also, in addition to disable the confirmation alerts you need to use:

`xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False`

You also need to set the `protection` first before saving.

PS. I summarized our discussion as an answer because it solved the question and can be helpful to future users.

Comment: I protected the worksheet without any password. That's why I didn't add the password part

Comment: The password field is optional.